# ANSI encoded text file in blob storage has corrupted characters when reading it in a logic app

Tags: azure, text, encoding

I have an issue with text files that are save to a blob storage and then iterated through using a logic app. The files come from a very old (but unfortunately very important) system. Access to it is highly restricted, so I have zero control over how the files are created.

They are uploaded to our blob storage without any suffix and with ANSI encoding. If I view their file contents through the Azure portal I can see that non-standard characters (in this case åäö) are corrupted :
[corrupted chars][1]

I assume this is because Azure assumes UTF-8 encoding? The problem occurs when I use a logic app to iterate through the blobs, then getting the file contents and placing them in a string variable. As far as I understood it, Azure logic apps should automatically convert the encoding to UTF-8, but this doesn't seem to happen, since the characters åäö in the string variable are still garbled.

The data from the string variable is used as input data for an Azure function that needs to be able to see the åäö characters properly. Manually converting the files to UTF-8 before uploading them solves the issue, but this is not practical, since this data flow is supposed to be automated.

The file contents are extracted like so:
[file contents to variable][2]

Infer content makes no difference, neither does renaming the files with a proper .txt suffix.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5B2ru.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zb6yj.png

Comment: No, it's because the text isn't ANSI or rather ASCII. It's some other single-byte codepage, which is a very bad idea. ASCII or rather, US-ASCII has no characters above 0x7F. UFT-8 by design uses the exact same bytes as US-ASCII. Your code used some other codepage, eg Latin1, to store the text. That's always a bad idea. Almost all web sites use UTF8, including StackOverflow. There's just no way to guess what encoding was used with single-byte codepages, so there's *always* a chance the wrong codepage will be used. That was solved when everyone moved to UTF8 20+ years ago

Comment: How was this text produced? That's where the bug is. Change that code to use UTF8 instead. Azure Functions or .NET can't automagically guess what encoding was used. Was it Windows-1251? 1252? 1253? All the code sees is byte values, that are valid in dozens of codepages. Your Azure Functions code would have to know and explicitly specify the encoding when reading text. Unicode and UTF8 were created to solve that problem

Comment: `converting the files to UTF-8 before uploading them solves the issue, but this is not practical,` quite the opposite. Generate the files using UTF8 from the start, so you don't have to convert anything. You didn't have to convert this page when you typed `åäö`. I didn't have to convert anything when typing `Αυτό Εδώ`. Without Unicode, these characters would never appear in the same page

Comment: Believe me, if I had control over how these files are generated, I would change the encoding to UTF-8 in a heartbeat. Unfortunately I don't which is my issue :-(

Comment: That's where the problem is though. EIther that code starts storing text in UTF8, or you need to find out what the correct encoding is and use it when loading the file's contents. If the encoding changes though, you'd have the same problem all over again. It looks like the contents are in Latin1 now, but what if you have to read Cyrillic or Greek text at some point? You could add a step to convert files to UTF8

Comment: Your workflow loads the blob contents as *binary*. Is there a step that can convert that binary content to text *before* you use it to initialize a text variable?

Comment: I could certainly add such a step, but I am not quite sure how to go about with converting the binary content to text.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with my windows.1252 encoded files. Added the parameter "Infer content type" in "Get blob content (v2)". Set it to No and it was solved for me. Got my æøå in the csv file and not some horrible UTF-8 encoding.